# After upgrading to rails 4.0.3 - Could not find 'minitest' (~> 5.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Why does my server not start by simply using rails s

```
→ rails s
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'minitest' (~> 5.1) - did find: [minitest-4.7.5] (Gem::LoadError)

→ bundle exec rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.1 codename Death Proof)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to do the following and now it works.

```
→ bundle clean --force
→ bundle update
→ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.1 codename Death Proof)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like in your `Gemfile` you are requiring `minitest (~> 5.1)`
but current version on your system is `4.7.5`
Run
`bundle update minitest`
it would update the `minitest` version.